# Gradle task dependency on other source folder classes

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am working on a gradle file which has 2 tasks with different src directories. Task 2 is dependent on some of the classes from task1. Is there any way i can mention that dependency in task2 and run them separately.

SouceSet1:

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integration-test/java')   
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
    }
}
```

SourceSet2:

```
sourceSets {
    functionTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/function-test/java')   
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
    }
}
```

Source set 1 runs fine but source set 2 through error of some methods which doesn't recognize because they are in sourceset 1 source folder. Is there any solution of this problem in gradle? I want to run both tasks separately.